# get all rows from A plus missing rows from B

Tags: sql, join, teradata

This seems so obvious but I am failing.

In Teradata SQL, how to get all rows from table A, plus those from table B, that do not occur in table A, based on key field key?

This must have been asked a thousand times. But honestly I do not find the answer.
Full outer join seems to give me duplicate "inner join" results.

--Edit , based on first comment (thanks) --
so if I would do

```
    select * from A
    union all 
    select * from B
        left join A
               on A.key = B.key
            where A.key IS NULL
```

I guess that would work (untested) but is that the most performant way?

Comment: Sounds like `UNION` to me.

Comment: thanks, I have updated the question based on the suggestion (performance )

Comment: No. `(SELECT ... FROM A) UNION (SELECT ... FROM B)`. No JOINs whatsoever.

Comment: the rows are not identical, just the keys are so this is going to give duplicate key rows; ie, it is not going to work i think..UNION vs UNION ALL only considers identical rows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes `EXISTS` or `NOT EXISTS` performs better than joins:

```
select * from A
union all 
select * from B
where not exists (
  select 1 from A
  where A.key = B.key
)
```

I assume the `key` columns are already indexed.

Comment: you are right,  this was the first reply, so marking this one as the answer

Answer (score 2):

Your version is fine . . . if you select the right columns:

```
select A.* from A
union all 
select B.*
from B left join
     A
     on A.key = B.key
 where A.key IS NULL;
```

I think Teradata does a good job optimizing joins.  That said, `EXISTS` is also a very reasonable option.

Comment: ok thanks, this is confirmation enough that there is no quicker 'one-pass' solution. And also pointed to the EXISTS solution. Thanks!